# Relation betwwen the expectation value of the position operator in Bloch state with unitary position operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, topological-insulators

Recently, I want to get some knowledge about topological insulators, so I read the [*A short course on topological insulators*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.02295). In the chapter 3, the author try to explain why polarization connects with Berry phase. Author show a unitary position operator:
[image]

Then he show the connection between the expectation value of the position operator in Bloch State with the phase of the expectation value of X, but I cannot get the some result
[image]

[image]

In my way, I think the $|m\rangle$ just mean the atomic orbital wave functions in the mth unit cell, then I would get $\langle\Psi|\hat{X}|\Psi\rangle=0$. I don't know how to get this relation, wish you can help me.